# Printing from a structure pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have defined a structure using `typedef struct` and then created a pointer in a function. I pass this pointer into a second function to assign values to the structure elements.

```
typedef struct 
{
    double velocity; // there are more variables than this but its the 
                     // same for each variable so only showing it for one.
}Variables;

void information(Variables **constants);


int main()
{
double k;


Variables *Constants=NULL; // the structure variable

information(&Constants); // passed into the 'filling' function


k=Constants->velocity;
printf("Velocity %lf\n",k); //this displays correctly

printf("Velocity %lf\n",Constants->velocity); // this does not display correctly

return;
}

 void information(Variables **Constants)
{
 Variables *consts,constants; //creates the struct to be filled
consts=&constants; 

 constants.velocity=30.2;

*Constants=consts;  //assigns the pointer to the pointer passed into the function
return;

}
```

here you can see I display the velocity twice. The first time I assign the value from the pointer to a variable and everything works perfectly. If I try and directly display using the line `printf("Velocity %lf\n",Constants->velocity);` the code gives a random number.

I have displayed numbers using the `.dot` format for structures before but never via a pointer so I do not understand what might be going wrong.

Comment: where is information function? Add complete code.

Comment: Please show how `Variables` is declared.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that the `velocity` field is `int` or `long` or anything else than `double`.

Comment: Added the code for the struct, hope that helps.  The information function literally just assigns a value to the velocity.

Comment: If "the information function literally just assigns a value to the velocity", then you must be not only forgetting to allocate any actual memory for your `struct`, but dereferencing a null pointer in the process. Very fishy. Post a minimum working example showing all the relevant code, otherwise you are just wasting everyone's time.

Comment: Added the `information()` function

Answer (score 0):

It's because of promotion. It has nothing to do with `struct` or with pointers.

Illustration:

```
double k;
int i;

i = 123456;
k = i;       // here i is promoted to double before the assignment
             // takes place, now k contains 123456.0000

printf("Velocity %lf\n", k);  // this displays correctly
                              // because k is a double and %lf is the format
                              // specifier for double

printf("Velocity %lf\n", i);  // this does not display correctly
                              // because i is an int and if you use the %lf
                              // format specifier with an int, then you will
                              // get undefined behaviour hence the garbage
                              // that is printed

printf("Velocity %lf\n", (double)i);
                              // this does not display correctly because the cast
                              // converts the int to a double
```

Comment: Hmm i thought that fixed it but i am still getting a problem. It became intermittent.

Comment: Please ask another question and provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).